# Distinct not working with lambda Duplicate drop down list values

Tags: c#, lambda, distinct

I am populating a drop down list by datasource from my DB , however my DB have duplicate values ( same column)which relfects on my drop down list having duplicate values .

i am using entity framework and lambda so i tried this:

```
  public IList<ModelSQL.puzzlecontent> GetID(int id)
    {
        return context.puzzlecontents.Where(i => i.WordPuzzleID == id).Distinct().ToList();
    }
```

ModelSQL is my folder name that consists of my CRUD class file ( puzzlecontent ) .

However the above code doesn't show any error but it doesn't help in removing the duplicate values in the drop down list .

Comment: When are the rows to be called `duplicated`? they have the same `WordPuzzleID`?

Comment: please include information about the class `PuzzleContent` and what you mean by "duplicate" values. Since clearly the reason for "duplicate" values must be due to your database having "duplicate" rows. What are you trying to return data distinct on?

Comment: As @Aron said. Your current code is distincting the values by `WordPuzzleID`, which is probably not what you'd want. If it is, you should redesign the database as there should never be duplicate ids as it's not id if it's duplicated.

Comment: i don't have duplicate rows , i have many different rows while some rows can belong to the same WordPuzzleID , in this case WordPuzzleID is a foreign key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use GroupBy

```
public IList<ModelSQL.puzzlecontent> GetID(int id)
{
   //for grouping by multiple properties you can use Groupby like
   // .GroupBy(i=>new { i.WordPuzzleID,i.SecondProperty})
   return context.puzzlecontents
                 .Where(i => i.WordPuzzleID == id)
                 .GroupBy(i=>i.WordPuzzleID)
                 .Select(g=>g.First()).ToList();
}
```

or for LINQ to Objects You can use DistinctBy of [MoreLinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/)

```
public IList<ModelSQL.puzzlecontent> GetID(int id)
    {
        return context.puzzlecontents.Where(i => i.WordPuzzleID == id).DistinctBy(i=>i.WordPuzzleID ).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Hi i have tried your codes , GroupBy doesn't help and DistinctBy will give an error " does not contain definition " .

Comment: For DistinctBy you need to add the library i linked in my answer. And why doesn't groupby work? both should work. Do you want to get distinct on the basis of word puzzle id or is their any other key? Read my comment.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling Distinct on all the columns. If you have a column that is unique e.g. Auto Identity in that table you will always get all the records.

Use select before distinct and select only required columns and exclude the unique column

```
 public IList<ModelSQL.puzzlecontent> GetID(int id)
    {
        return context.puzzlecontents.Where(i => i.WordPuzzleID == id).Select(pc=>new{
              Column1 = pc.Column1,Column2 = pc.Column2    
        }).Distinct().ToList();
    }
```